# Como criar janelas simultâneas e exibi-las em duas telas diferentes com Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, gui

Então, estou criando um projeto no qual tenho uma janela principal com uma lista de imagens, que podem ser selecionadas em um OptionMenu, Gostaria de poder selecionar uma dessas imagens e exibi-la em uma segunda tela(literalmente, em outro monitor, ou em uma televisão) com um comando de um botão. Coloco abaixo um código de exemplo da tela principal que tenho:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

import customtkinter
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
from customtkinter import CTkButton

main_window = Tk()
main_window.geometry('400x400')
main_window.configure(bg="black")
main_window.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
main_window.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

s = ttk.Style()
s.configure('new.TFrame', background='black')


frm = ttk.Frame(main_window, borderwidth=1, relief='raised', style='new.TFrame')

frm.grid(row=0, column=0, rowspan=2, sticky='news', pady=10, padx=10)

ttk.Label(
    frm, text="Imagens", font=('Helvetica', 15, 'bold'), foreground='white', background='black').grid(
    column=0, row=0, columnspan=2, sticky="news", pady=2, padx=2)


valores = []
for _, _, arquivo in os.walk('imagens'):
    valores = arquivo


valor_dict = {}
for valor in valores:
    valor_dict[valor] = ImageTk.PhotoImage(
        Image.open("imagens/{}".format(valor)).resize(size=(350, 220)))

variavel = StringVar()
variavel.set(valores[0])


def change_image(e):
    imagem.config(image=valor_dict[e])


imagens = customtkinter.CTkOptionMenu(frm, values=valores, variable=variavel, command=change_image)

imagens.configure(font=('Helvetica', 14, 'bold'), dropdown_text_color='black', fg_color='black', hover=False, button_color='black', bg_color='black')

imagens.grid(column=0, row=2, columnspan=2, pady=4, sticky='news', padx=2)


base = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open('base.jpg').resize(size=(350, 220)))

imagem = ttk.Label(frm, image=base)
imagem.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=10, columnspan=2, sticky='ns')


def exibir_imagem():
    pass

def parar_exibicao():
    pass



CTkButton(
    master=frm, text='Exibir', font=('Helvetica', 14, 'bold'), corner_radius=9, bg_color='black', fg_color='black', border_color='grey', border_width=2).grid(
    row=3, column=0, pady=2, sticky='news')
CTkButton(
    master=frm, text='Parar', font=('Helvetica', 14, 'bold'), corner_radius=9, bg_color='black', fg_color='black', border_color='grey', border_width=2).grid(
    row=3, column=1, pady=2, sticky='news')

frm.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
frm.columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
frm.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
frm.rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
frm.rowconfigure(2, weight=1)
frm.rowconfigure(3, weight=1)


main_window.mainloop()
```

Peço que ignorem a qualidade da escrita do código, sou bastante novo em programação.
Procurei por um bom tempo online e não encontrei alguma dica que funcione para essa ideia.
Alguém saberia me dizer se é algo possível de se fazer? E se sim, qual seria o caminho?
Obrigado

P.s.: Há duas funções no código que ainda não foram definidas, por não saber ainda como realizar essa exibição em outra tela.